# Making a simple LED indicator with Qt

Tags: javascript, html, c++, css, qt

Hi I want to create a LED indicator with `Qt` based on `CSS`, from http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-leds I have created a label with rich text as source: `<div class="led-red"></div>` and as style-sheet:

```
margin: 20px auto;
width: 12px;
height: 12px;
background-color: #940;
border-radius: 50%;
```

I removed `box-shadow` since `Qt` doesn't recognize it.

- Why the render is a square and not a circle, I also tried with radio it supposed to work too but it didn't?
- How can I apply some fancy styles, such as `JavaScript` or some `CSS` that are not supported by `Qt` to buttons?

Answer (score 3):

Qt widgets such as QLabel or QTexEdit support only a subset of HTML 4 ([QLabel documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html)).

So `border-radius`, a CSS3 property, is likely not supported.

If you want to show a LED you can:

- Create a LED widget class by subclassing `QWidget` and draw the LED you want in the paintEvent() function.
- Add a pixmap/image to an existing widget. (`QLabel::setPixmap()`, `QPushButton::setIcon()`, etc.)

On a side note, you cannot really customize a GUI with CSS and javascript while using Qt widgets. They do support stylesheets and some of them handle rich text, but stylesheets break QStyle mechanisms and rich text does not follow HTML5/CSS3 standards.